# Handling convolutional neural network with incomplete data

Tags: algorithm, machine-learning, neural-network, conv-neural-network

I am working on a CNN using a set of triangle meshes (.obj files) of human faces that are topologically unified (they all have an equal number of vertices in the same order). I firstly map meshes onto a 2D grid while trying to keep vertices that are close to each other in 3D mesh also close to each other on 2D grid. My CNN input will be then, so to say, a 2D image with vertex 3D coordinates. The problem is that after running my algorithm that maps 3D mesh on a 2D grid on my data, the vertices are obviously spread across the grid unevenly and some grid cells are empty.

For example, for this mesh with eight vertices with triangles defined like this:

```
f 5 6 1  
f 4 1 3  
f 1 2 3  
f 1 4 5  
f 1 2 6  
f 5 6 7  
f 5 2 8
```

This is the 2D mapping generated by my algorithm (where the numbers are vertex indices, zero means and empty cell):

```
0       7       0   
8       2       6   
3       5       1   
0       4       0
```

Here I got 4 zeros in corners, but with larger meshes empty cells tend to be both between the valid vertices and in the corners around them.

My question is, what would be the best way to handle empty cells? I had some ideas but I am not sure if it's a correct way to do it:

- if zero is surrounded with vertices, I might replace zero with a calculated average of coordinates of surrounding vertices (which would not work in corners)
- replacing zero with a copy of a vertex

What would happen if I placed (0,0,0) vertex when data is missing?